# Bluebird each function throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, bluebird

Hi I am trying to understand what's wrong with the code below.

**Code:**

```
    const Promise = require('bluebird')
    const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

    var  config = {
      "files": [{
        "path1": "bla.js",
        "path2": "bla.js"
      }]
    }
    var baseDir ='./'
    function validateConfig(config) {
      return Promise.each(config.files, (file) => 
        Promise.each([file.path1, file.path2], (path) =>{
          fs.statAsync(baseDir+ path)
          console.log(baseDir + path)
        }

        )
      )
    }

validateConfig(config).then(config => validateConfig(config))
```

I have no clue why this is happening? Would be nice if someone could explain it.

```
TypeError: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]]
```

**Edit:**
I created an self contained example which shows the problem.
The error happens in the last line

`validateConfig(config).then(config => validateConfig(config))`

This is just an example. normally I would call another method in `.then()`

Comment: Does it give a line numnber? Your current snippet doesn't compile

Comment: There is no linenumber. I will try to create an executable example.

Comment: For this to work properly, `config.files` would need to be an array of objects where the objects had properties on them `.path1` and `.path2`.  The error message makes me think that isn't the case.  Please, show us what `config.files` is.  For example, do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(config.files));` and show us what that is.

Comment: @CallumLinington 
I edited my question. The code should now be executable and reproduce my error.

Comment: @jfriend00 edited my Question it now contains executable code which reproduces the error

Comment: Yeah the issue with your code is that `.then(config => validateConfig(config))` You're recursively validating config....

Comment: Your new code example makes no sense.  Why are you calling `validateConfig()` recursively?  And, the second call to `validateConfig()` is not passing the desired data format either.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with that

```
.then(config => validateConfig(config));
```

It is calling back into `validateConfig` with some kind of `config` object that doesn't look the same as the const you gave it in the first place.

I solved your issue like this:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

const config = {
    "files": [{
        "path1": "bla.js",
        "path2": "bla.js"
    }]
};

const baseDir = './';

function validateConfig(config) {
    return Promise.all(
        config.files
            .reduce((fileList, file) => fileList.concat([file.path1, file.path2]), []) // this just gives you a list of files
            .map(path => fs.statAsync(baseDir + path)) // this returns the promises of stat'ing each file
    )
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

validateConfig(config)
    .then(statFiles => console.log(statFiles));
```